# Basic reversed url breaking jquery call

Tags: php, jquery, html

Having problem i guess it's with the url or some kind of stuff. I just can't see what it is. I posted the jquery part, maybe I've got something wrong or terribly out of date?

It just doesn't append to my actual link where would go the php file.

> url.127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2016:20:54:19 -0500] "POST
>   /projectBox/php/add_box.php HTTP/1.1" 200 224
>   "http://localhost/projectBox/?txtBox=test&txtDetail=test" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"

```
            $('#addProject').click(function(event) 
        {
            var dataProject = $('form[name="frmAddProject"]').serialize();

            $.ajax({
            data: dataProject,
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/add_box.php',
            dataType: 'html',
              success: function(data) 
              {
                 if(data == 1)
                 {
                        alert("réusssi");
                 }
                 else if (data == 0) {
                    alert("erreur d'enregistrement!");
                 }
              },
              error: function(jqxhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) 
              {
                console.log(dataProject);
                 $('#error').text("ERROR : " + jqxhr.status + " " + errorThrown + " " + error);
                 $('#error').toggle();
                    //$('#error').animate({width: 'toggle'}).delay(5000).hide(1);
              }
           });
        });
```

here are my html tags

```
            <form name="frmAddProject">
            <div id="input_dialogue" class="hide">
                <h3>Add project Box</h3>
                <hgroup>
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input id="txtBox" name="txtBox">

                </hgroup>
                <hgroup>

                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input id="txtDetail" name="txtDetail">

                </hgroup>

                <button id="addProject">
                    Add
                </button>

            </div>
        </form>
```

this is the php part

```
include('./connect.php');

$myBox = $_POST['txtBox'];  
$myDetail = $_POST['txtDetail'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO pbo_projects('pbo_title', 'pbo_description') 
          VALUES ('".$myBox."', '".$myDetail."')";

if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    $mysqli->close();
    return "1";
}
else
{   
    $mysqli->close();
    return "0";
}
```

**EDIT 2ND ERROR***
I also made a function to get the different projects and I get an 500 status code in my JQuery, but as I alert the .error from the data I get *don't now if it's of any help, it seems to give me some Jquery stuff I can't read.

the alert shows:

> function (){if(h){var c=h.length;!function
>   g(b){n.each(b,function(b,c){var
>   d=n.type(c);"function"===d?a.unique&&k.has(c)||h.push(c):c&&c.length&&"string"!==d&&g(c)})}(arguments),d?f=h.length:b&&(e=c,j(b))}return
>   this}

there is the jquery part:

```
        function loadProjects() 
    {

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: './php/load_projects.php',
            success: function(data) 
            {
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert(data.error);
                console.log(data.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

load_projects.php part

```
    include('./connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT pbo_title, pbo_description
            FROM pbo_projects ";

$result = $mysqli-­>query($sql); #line 8 says Use of undefined constant \xc2\xad - assumed '\xc2\xad' ## this is my access.log
$titles = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $titles[] = array('title' => $row['pbo_title'], 'description' => $row['pbo_description']);
}
echo json_encode($titles);
```

Anymore thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$myBox = $_GET['txtBox'];
$myDetail = $_GET['txtDetail'];
```

Comment: Oowh Thank you! Got that working after putting all my posts to gets and then solved little other problems here and there but got it allright. I'll post back if I have any special issues which i don't fully understand... does it really post or get... well thanks again. Stay in touch I'll submit anymore code to my github when have enough ready so you guys can have a sneak if you care! This is like a classifying project project!;)

Thanks again